# Strong solution of SDE: Do the driving Brownian Motion and the initial value determine the underlying probability space?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

The following formulation of the theorem due Yamada-Watanabe can be found in *"On the Existence of Universal Functional Solutions to Classical SDE'S"* (Kallenberg, O., 1996).

> Assume that weak existence and pathwise uniqueness hold for solutions
>   starting at arbitrary fixed points. Then strong existence and
>   uniqueness in law hold for every initial distribution. Furthermore,
>   there exists a Borel measurable and universally predictable function
>   $F(x,w)$ such that any solution $(X, B) $ satisfies $X = F(X(0), B)$
>   a.s.

Since weak solutions (for a given initial distribution $\mu=\delta_x$) might be defined on different probability spaces, then shouldn't the function $F$ depend on the probability space?

I mean, suppose we have a given initial distribution $\mu=\delta_x$, assume two solutions $(X,B)$ and $(X',B)$ exist on **two different filtered probability spaces** $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_t,P)$ and $(\Omega', \mathcal F', \mathcal F_t',P')$ such that $X(0)$ and $X'(0)$ are distributed as $\mu$ i.e. $X(0)=X'(0)=x\in\mathbb R^d$.
(This is not incompatible with the pathwise uniqueness since the solutions are defined in different probability spaces).

Hence the solutions should by the previous theorem be $X=F(x,B)=X'$ a.s. but this two solutions live in different probability spaces!

Am I missing something?

At this point my doubt reduces to, given a Brownian motion and an initial value, does this suffice to determine the underlying probability space unambiguously?

Thanks in advance.